# Laravel - NULL on columns

Tags: php, sql, laravel, null, nullable

I add two columns at my `users` table, Viber and Whatsapp with two artisan commands `php artisan make:migration add_viber_to_users` and `php artisan make:migration add_whatsapp_to_users`. And these are my migrations:

Viber migration:

```
/**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('viber')->after('status')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

And Whatsapp migration:

```
/**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('whatsapp')->after('viber')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

And in my `RegisterController`:

```
/**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'telefon' => ['required', 'numeric', 'unique:users', 'min:6'],
            'drzava' => ['required'],
            'grad' => ['required'],
            'status' => ['required'],
            'viber' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            'whatsapp' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'telefon' => $data['telefon'],
            'drzava' => $data['drzava'],
            'grad' => $data['grad'],
            'status' => $data['status'],
            'viber' => $data['viber'],
            'whatsapp' => $data['whatsapp'],
        ]);
    }
```

Also, this is my form select fields for `viber` and `whatsapp`:

```
<select class="form-control{{ $errors->has('viber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" required name="viber" id="inputGroupSelect01">
   <option selected>Viber</option>
   <option value="1">Da</option>
   <option value="0">Ne</option>
</select>
@if($errors->has('viber'))
<div class="invalid-feedback">
   {{ $errors->first('viber') }}
</div>
@endif
```

```
<select class="form-control{{ $errors->has('whatsapp') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" required name="whatsapp" id="inputGroupSelect01">
   <option selected>Viber</option>
   <option value="1">Da</option>
   <option value="0">Ne</option>
</select>
@if($errors->has('whatsapp'))
<div class="invalid-feedback">
   {{ $errors->first('whatsapp') }}
</div>
@endif
```

**PROBLEM HERE**

My problem here is whenever I register a new user and I select both `viber` and `whatsapp` fields for `Da` so the value is `1` in my database it is stored like `NULL`.
I don't see the problem here?
How can I fix this ?

Comment: did you add these 2 fields to the `fillable` array on the model? it will just ignore any fields not in that list when using mass assignment like that

Comment: I totally forgot, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. ensure you run `php artisan migrate` and already migrated to your table
2. ensure to add new columns to `fillable` array in your model.

Comment: Fillable array was problem, I totally forgot about that